# Use of imageCropAndScaleOption and regionOfInterest in VNCoreMLRequest

Tags: apple-vision

What happens if I use both imageCropAndScaleOption and regionOfInterest. What's the effect of the following codes

```
request.imageCropAndScaleOption = .centerCrop
request.regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.25, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)
```

`request` is a `VNCoreMLRequest`

Will the input be `CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.25, width: 1.0, height: 0.5)` with respect to the entire image or the center-cropped image?

Also I found when I just `imageCropAndScaleOption` to be `.centerCrop`, and if my CoreML model has an input of size 800x400, Vision API actually takes the **largest centered square** image from the camera, and resizes it into 800x400 before feeding into my model. It is different from their document:

> maintaining aspect ratio to fit the short side, while cropping the centered image on its long side.